# How to get/set global Google Chrome Content Settings for Images in an Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written an extension for Google Chrome to toggle loading of images on and off using a Browser Action button.

It works but so far I can only set and get the value for *specific* pages by URL. These settings are surfaced under the **Manage exceptions...** button of the **Settings > Under the Bonnet > Privacy > Content Settings... > Images** section. For example,

```js
chrome.contentSettings['images'].get({
    'primaryUrl': 'http://www.example.com/*',
    'incognito': false
},
function(details) {
    console.log('Show images: ' + details.setting);
});
```

will output the message "Show images: allow" or "Show images: block".

But I would like to be able to turn the global setting on and off. I therefore need to  know if the value is "Show all images (recommended)" or "Do not show any images" under **Settings > Under the Bonnet > Privacy > Content Settings... > Images**, i.e., whether **allow** or **blocked** is the *default*?

Various attempts at using wildcards for the `primaryUrl`, such as the following, throws an error:

```js
chrome.contentSettings['images'].get({
    'primaryUrl': '*://*/*',
    'incognito': false
},
function(details) {
    console.log('Show images: ' + details.setting);
});
```

ERROR:

```js
'Error during contentSettings.get: The URL "*://*/*" is invalid.'
```

Referencing [Content Settings](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSettings.html#property-images) and [Match Patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) has me thinking I need to use special `<all_urls>` pattern but I'm getting errors with that too.

Comment: Have you tried just `*` (one asterisk)? It works in manifests, should work there too.

Comment: A single `*` doesn't work either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safe enough to think that the global setting is being applied on "example.com"? Then you can use the `set` method to change the global settings for `<all_urls>`.

Comment: what is the name of the extension? does it still work for current stable chrome version?

Answer (score 2):

For the contentSettings.get you can use 'http://*' or the current tab's url. `'<all_urls>'` works for primaryPattern in contentSettings.set.

```
function toggleImages(tab) {

    chrome.contentSettings['images'].get({
        primaryUrl: tab.url
    }, function (details) {
        chrome.contentSettings['images'].set({
            primaryPattern: '<all_urls>',
            setting: details.setting == 'allow' ? 'block' : 'allow'
        })
    });

}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(toggleImages);
```